# Why isnt my #lowerbody div not centering?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs ids inside another div. (#leftbody, #rightbody, #lowerbody) The left and right body are good but my lower body seems to stay to the left even after I set the left and right margin to auto.

```css
.Header {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  width: calc(100%-16px);
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.MidBody {
  background-color: #141414;
  width: calc(100%-16px);
  height: 850px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  width: calc(100%-16px);
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#leftbody {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  width: 49%;
  height: 425px;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: .25;
}
#rightbody {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  width: 49%;
  height: 425px;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: .25;
}
#lowerbody {
  width: 98%;
  height: 49%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 430px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Header"></div>
  <div class="MidBody">
    <div id="leftbody"></div>
    <div id="rightbody"></div>
    <div id="lowerbody"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: It won't center because you gave it absolute positioning.

Comment: Wow thank you im still new to this. After I took that off it pushed up over top of the left and right body. How can i fix that?

Comment: See LGSon's solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `right: 0; left: 0;` to its CSS rule it will.

```css
.Header {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  width: calc(100%-16px);
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.MidBody {
  background-color: #141414;
  width: calc(100%-16px);
  height: 850px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  width: calc(100%-16px);
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#leftbody {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  width: 49%;
  height: 425px;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: .25;
}
#rightbody {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  width: 49%;
  height: 425px;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: .25;
}
#lowerbody {
  width: 98%;
  height: 49%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 430px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Header"></div>
  <div class="MidBody">
    <div id="leftbody"></div>
    <div id="rightbody"></div>
    <div id="lowerbody"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
```

---

Even if above works, you might want to use some other way for layout than `position: absolute`, for example like this, which is more responsive and will flow better.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.Container {
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.Header {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.MidBody {
  background-color: #141414;  
  height: 850px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#leftbody {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 3px 3px 0 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: .25;
}
#rightbody {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 3px 3px 0 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: .25;
}
#lowerbody {
  height: 49%;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Header"></div>
  <div class="MidBody">
    <div id="leftbody"></div>
    <div id="rightbody"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="lowerbody"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```